# Spring Data Neo4j - Combining Fulltext and Simple Indexes in the same Cypher query

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I wonder how can i build a Cypher query that will combine Fulltext and Simple indexes using spring data neo4j. Consider the following node entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class SomeObject {

    public SomeObject() {

    }

    public SomeObject(String name, int height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "search_name")
    String name;

    @Indexed(numeric = false)
    int height;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

OK, so my question is how can i run a query (By using a `SomeObject` Graph Repository) that will start from `SomeObject` nodes, by referencing their simple indexes and full-text indexes in the same query. For example i would like to write something like that:

```
START n=node:SomeObject('name: Roy AND height: [170 TO 190]') RETURN n
```

I know that i cannot write it exactly like that, because spring data neo4j forces me to give a seperate index name for fields that are needed to be FULLTEXT indexed. But what if i need make an index lookup for my `SomeObject` entity which combines both fileds? (name & height)

What are the best practices in such case? Is there a way to combine them both in the same query? or maybe should i query each of them separably, and then to perform some some kind of intersection between the two results, so i will get exactly the nodes the meet my original query lookup condition? (`name: Roy AND height: [170 TO 190]`).

Thanks!
Roy.

Answer (score 1):

I'd never launch two separate queries. Maybe just use one index as a starting point in your query?

```
START n=node:search_name('name: Roy')
WHERE n.height >= 170 AND n.height <= 190
RETURN n
```

How's the performance of this query? This bypasses the SomeObject index, but I don't see any other option as you indeed cannot combine both indexes.

I as also thinking about the following query, but you'd still end up with duplicates:

```
START n=node:search_name('name: Roy'), m=node:SomeObject('height: [170 TO 190]')
RETURN DISTINCT n,m
```

Comment: I thought about two options:

1. So the first option is to run two queries, and then manually intersect the results of the two queries, so i will be left with the nodes that meets the conditions of both queries.

2. The other option is maybe something similar to what you wrote (the second query you suggested), but also add a WHERE clause that makes sure the the graph ids of **m** and **n** is the same, so i will get only nodes that meet both conditions. is it possible? i can't check it right now, but i will try to give an answer this evening.

Comment: Adding the WHERE clause won't help, but I don't know any ohter option. Please let me know what the performance of my first query was.